# how to build name sequence in my sql innodb

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I have a table with three columns, name , sequence, preference
For example,
If we have Lawrence who likes beef
it will be
Lawrence, 0, beef,
then Mike who likes pork
it will be
Mike, 0, pork.
if there is another Lawrence who likes chicken,
it will automatically be
Lawrence, 1, chicken.

In myisam, we used to set the sequence as autoincrement.
When we switches to innodb, it does not allow us to build autoincrement as the second key column.

What can we do in innodb to achieve the same effects as setting the aotuincrement as the second index column?

Comment: I don't know of a way to set up the table to do that automatically. You still have a few options I can see. 1 - Complicated insert that counts data while you insert to get the sequence before inserting. 2 - Have a trigger update the sequence on insert. 3 - Remove that column from that table and have a view to show that column since it can be calculated after the data has been inserted. Lemme know if those work and I can help you with either of those options.

Comment: MyISAM (deprecated) has such a feature.  See [_this_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb#index_issue_2_column_pk) as a possible workaround.